# How do do a nested transaction without stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am trying to write a nested transaction without using stored procedures. What is the structure for it. I tried it but getting a few errors. Some of my variables are not picking up and when I try to declare them it says they are already been declared.

```
Begin Transaction campOffer
    Begin Transaction loyaltyCard
        Begin Transaction marketingList
            Insert Into marketing_list values (@custID, @name, @dOB,  
  @gender, @parish, @mobile, @mProvider, @mStatus)
            Select @@TRANCOUNT

            Commit Transaction
        End

        Insert Into Loyalty_Card (Member_ID) Values (@memID)
        Select @@TRANCOUNT

        Commit Transaction
    End

    Insert Into Campaign_Offer values (@offID, @offDate, @custID, @offValue, @prodName, @accepStatus, @empID)
    Select @@TRANCOUNT

    Commit Transaction
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Outside of a stored procedure, you will have to declare and then set values for all of your parameters.

```
    declare @custID as int, @name as varchar(10), @dOB as date,@gender as varchar(1) 
    --.... (do this for all with appropriate data types)

    -- then set the desired values.
    Set @custID = 101;
        Set @name = 'johnny';
        --(Set all param values)


    Begin Transaction campOffer
    Begin Transaction loyaltyCard
        Begin Transaction marketingList
            Insert Into marketing_list values (@custID, @name, @dOB,  
                                                @gender, @parish, @mobile, @mProvider, @mStatus)
            Select @@TRANCOUNT

            Commit Transaction
        End

        Insert Into Loyalty_Card (Member_ID) Values (@memID)
        Select @@TRANCOUNT

        Commit Transaction
    End

    Insert Into Campaign_Offer values (@offID, @offDate, @custID, @offValue, @prodName, @accepStatus, @empID)
    Select @@TRANCOUNT

    Commit Transaction
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested transactions are a myth. Ok. You can have them. But SQL Server only considers the outermost transaction as the real one. You can't rollback an inner one. It will rollback the outermost transaction. See MSDN general remarks section for both the [COMMIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx) and [ROLLBACK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) statements for more details.

You have a small issue understanding `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. This is not a block statement like `BEGIN` by itself is. So, once you declare a variable, it's scope doesn't leave at the COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement.

```
Begin Transaction campOffer --@@TRANCOUNT = 1
Begin Transaction loyaltyCard --@@TRANCOUNT = 2
Begin Transaction marketingList --@@TRANCOUNT = 3
Insert Into marketing_list values (@custID, @name, @dOB, @gender,
    @parish, @mobile, @mProvider, @mStatus)
Select @@TRANCOUNT

Commit Transaction --@@TRANCOUNT = 2
--END -- does not correspond to any BEGIN statement

Insert Into Loyalty_Card (Member_ID) Values (@memID)
Select @@TRANCOUNT

Commit Transaction --@@TRANCOUNT = 1
-- END -- does not correspond to any BEGIN statement

Insert Into Campaign_Offer values (@offID, @offDate, @custID, @offValue, @prodName, @accepStatus, @empID)
Select @@TRANCOUNT

Commit Transaction --@@TRANCOUNT = 0... outer transaction is now committed.
--END -- does not correspond to any BEGIN statement
```

Comment: Oh I thought begin transaction was like a block statement.,thanks man